# PHP form Action add $ variable

Tags: php

Is it possible to add in an form action an `$ variable` ?

I want generate an random number after my url.

**script:**

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

On this way its dont work:

```
<form action=' . $welcome . $urlext' method="post">
```

Code i want add like this:

```
$welcome= "welcome.php";

header('Location:' . $welcome . $urlext);
```

Url looks like this after it: `welcome?Ssh4bVY0cKAy`

The Problem, i must do it within the `form action=""` because i have connected all my `SESSION` in my big script and if i use `if button submit then redirect`
i must change much code.

Hope anyone can help me and thats possible!

Comment: Try : `<form action="<?php echo $welcome . $urlext; ?>" method="post">`

Comment: Oh my god, I'm such an idiot xD Many Thanks! Sure i cant add an `$` without `<?php`

Comment: Works this also in  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=/page3">` ?